# kespersy cann't allow password to store in db

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I'm using kespersy antivirus.I want to store the details in database.but password and confirm password value is not printed while testing.
 all the field values are echoed except password and confirm password.$pass is password variable and $c_pass is confirm password variable.

```
<form name="profile" method="post">

         <p style="margin-left:1cm">Name<a style="margin-left:45px"></a>&nbsp: <input type="text" name="p_name" size=18 maxlength=50></p>
         <p style="margin-left:1cm">Email<a style="margin-left:45px"></a>&nbsp: <input type="text" name="email" size=18 maxlength=50></p>
         <p style="margin-left:1cm">Password<a style="margin-left:25px"></a>&nbsp: <input type="password" name="pass" size=18 maxlength=50></p>
         <p style="margin-left:1cm">Confirm<a style="margin-left:30px"></a>&nbsp: <input type="password" name="c_pass" size=18 maxlength=50></p>
         <p style="margin-left:1cm">Phone<a style="margin-left:45px"></a>&nbsp: <input type="text" name="phone" size=18 maxlength=50></p>
         <p style="margin-left:1cm">Address<a style="margin-left:30px"></a> : <textarea name="address" max=200></textarea></p>
         <p style="margin-left:1cm">EIN<a style="margin-left:50px"></a>  &nbsp :  <textarea name="ein" max=200></textarea></p>
         <center><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" /> </center>
        </form>
 <?php
 include "config.php";
 if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']))
 {
  echo "hai";
  echo $pass=$_REQUEST['Pass'];
   echo $c_pass=$REQUEST['c_pass'];
   echo $address=$_REQUEST['address'];
   echo $p_name=$_REQUEST['p_name'];
   echo $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
   echo $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
   echo $ein=$_REQUEST['ein'];
    echo $datz=date('m-d-yy h:i:s');
    if($pass==$c_pass)
    {
    echo $c_pass;
    echo $pass;
      if($p_name!='' && $address!='' && $p_name!='' && $phone!='' && $email!='' && $ein!='' && $pass!='')
 {
  echo $sql="insert into register(name,address,contact_name,phone,email,password,ein,c_date) values ('$name','$address','$p_name','$phone','$email','$pass','$ein','$datz')";
   if(mysql_query($sql))
    {
      echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.alert('registered successfully');

       </SCRIPT>");
    }
  else
  {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.alert('try again');

       </SCRIPT>");   
      } 
 }
}
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Plaintext passwords, XSS and SQL injection; you've got it all ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all why do you use the $_REQUEST variable?

It would be much safer if you use $_POST instead.

Can you update your question with your HTML form so we can see what you did there?

Another suggestions is to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions or even [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

With prepared statements you are better protected against SQL injections like Jack mentioned.

If you dont use prepared statements it is really important that you escape the user input before you save it in your Database:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $name);
```

And you should not save the passwords in plaintext, at least use MD5.

```
$pass = md5($pass);
```

Better use SHA1 as mentioned by BlackPearl:

```
$pass = sha1($pass);
```

UPDATE:

I see a typo in your HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="pass" size=18 maxlength=50></p>
```

But in your PHP Code you use:

```
$_REQUEST['Pass']
```

which is wrong.

you have to use the same name it is case sensitive.

Comment: `sha1` is better but still vulnerable.